# Getting rid of index in URL when using CodeIgniter and HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, https, url-rewriting

I've been working on a codeigniter application. When I first started developing it I used the following url structure:

http://somewebsite.com/application/login/

I changed the site to run over https

https://www.somewebsite.com/application/login/

The problem is any calls to the server only work like this.

https://www.somewebsite.com/application/index.php/login/

I want to get rid of the index.php.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The only impact using SSL would have is if SSL points to a different directory in which AllowOverride isn't enabled. If so, check serverfault.com. If not, check any of the 274 million results you get searching for "Codeigniter remove index.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have you .htaccess rewrite SSL properly.  This is an .htaccess I use that works - although it FORCES SSL.  Not sure if you want to do that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

check and edit the application/config/config.php.
in that change the following line

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

just remove `index.php` and then it should work lust fine...